# How do I write a summarize function in R?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a summarizing print function in R to with the outputs below. I'm not sure how to get it to print with a new line for each output. My code so far is below as well. Any help would be appreciated. 
Outputs:
Mean
Median
Min
Max
Standard deviation
Quantiles   (at 0.05    and 0.95)
Skewness

Here is my code so far

```
    printInfo <- function(myVector)
{
 print( 
  mean(myVector)
  median(myVector)
  min(myVector)
  max(myVector)
  sd(myVector)
  quantile(myVector, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))
  library(moments)
  skewness(myVector))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(moments)

printInfo <- function(myVector)
{
  cat( 
    "mean: ", mean(myVector), "\n",
    "median: ", median(myVector), "\n",
    "min: ", min(myVector), "\n",
    "max: ", max(myVector), "\n",
    "sd: ", sd(myVector), "\n",
    "quantile: ", quantile(myVector, probs = c(0.05, 0.95)), "\n",
    "skewness: ", skewness(myVector), "\n")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark! That is what I was trying to accomplish!